# selectionChange in mat-select not working Angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-select

I have created a mat-select with selectionChange event but when the value is changed the event is not fired.

**html file**

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="changeCategory()">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categoryList" [value]="category._id">{{category.name}} </mat-option> </mat-select>
```

**ts file**

```
changeCategory(){
    console.log('ok')
  }
```

Comment: refer: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

Answer (score 2):

import **MatSelectModule** in your **app.module.ts**

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a working demo to show the usage of `selectionChange` so you can compare it with your case to see what is missing: [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnkgw6?file=src/app/select-disabled-example.html)

Every time you change the selection, a number in the template is increase by 1 to show that the event is fired. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-select
            (selectionChange)="select($event)"
            required
            formControlName="adquiriente"
          >
```

You can try,  this way

```
select(event) {
    console.log(event.value);
    // let value = event.
  }
```